# Windows UI Automation API

Tags: c#, user-interface, automation, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I have been trying to figure this out for a while so any help would be greatly appreciated. I am using UI Automation in my client to monitor and report on user selection within another application. I got the code working perfectly on Server 2003. On Server 2008 however, the control which I am monitoring is being reported as either an item within a data grid or a list. It's very random and I noticed that if I keep on selecting rows within the control, eventually the control will be reported as a data grid. On server 2003, it was always reported as a data grid and so my code works perfectly.

I am developing in Visual Studio 2010 C#.

Update:

I wanted to mention that I got the same results using the UI Spy tool so the source-code is not relevant in this specific case.

Comment: without seeing source code this will be pure speculation like security, UAC, high/low priviliged processes and other stuff...

Comment: I got the same results using the UI Spy tool (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms727247.aspx) so the source-code is not necessary in this scenario.

Comment: Then the source of the target is rather relevant...

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking the time to comment. If by source of the target you mean the application that I am monitoring then it's a third-party application. I don't know much about the development of it other than what I can see through automation. I believe the windows which contain the controls are MDI. Is there more information that is needed in order to help troubleshoot this?

Comment: IMHO the reason for what you see most probably results from a mix of security measures added to the newer Windows version and how the target application is implemented (is it .NET-based ? is the control a Windows built-in one or some 3rd-party control ?)... I don't see how to diagnose this without taking the target application apart (either on source code level and/or with a debugger)... perhaps someone more skilled or with a similar experience as you describe can help with this...

Comment: The application is being reported as Win32 so it might be prior to .NET. I believe that it's a third-part control. (It's being reported as UltraGrid in UI Spy. I think it's the Infragistics UltraGrid)

The main issue is that the control might be old and wasn't designed with automation in mind because it's not reporting any of the standard patterns which are reported by standard windows grids. Because of this I had to use the LegacyIAccessiblePattern in order to retrieve the selections. May be this information helps, otherwise someone who experienced this needs to chime in.

Comment: Depending on several aspects the UltraGrid recreates its handle (sometimes even rather often)... this could mess with how it is perceived by UI automation... I don't think that there is anything you do about it from outside the target application...

Comment: According to [this](http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/t/50791.aspx) UltraGrid does NOT have any support for UI automation...

Comment: Cool, can you add your last comment an as answer? I will apply the bounty to it if nobody else chimes in within a couple days. Thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Currently the only automation of their control supported is their own TestAdvantage product - see http://blogs.infragistics.com/forums/p/10294/323529.aspx#323529

Comment: Yeah, I read that. Like I said, I had to use the LegacyIAccessiblePattern in combination with other logic in order to get the actual value from the user selection. Needless to say it was a painful process.

Comment: I posted my comments as answer...

Comment: Please read my comment, I actually posted my reply about the other comment and not about it not supporting automation. The control not supporting automation is not really pertinent to my OP since I am already automating it successfully. It's more about what you said in regards to recreating it's handle.

Comment: I rephrased my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on several aspects the UltraGrid recreates its handle (sometimes even rather often)... this could mess with how it is perceived by UI automation... I don't think that there is anything you can do about it from outside the target application...

*Additional information:*

The control in question (Infragistics UltraGrid) does NOT have any support for the Windows/MS UI Automation according to [this](http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/t/50791.aspx).

Currently the only automation solution supported is the [TestAdvantage product from the same vendor](http://blogs.infragistics.com/forums/p/10294/323529.aspx#323529).

Although they seem to be working on adding support for Windows UI automation within the next months...

Comment: Just to clarify, I was referring to this reply: Depending on several aspects the UltraGrid recreates its handle (sometimes even rather often)... this could mess with how it is perceived by UI automation... I don't think that there is anything you do about it from outside the target application

Comment: @DeviantSeev yes, that is the first paragraph - I just though for completeness/reference I add all information provided...

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect. I will award the bounty once I can.